# Group_by loop through different variables in survey data object

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, survey

Here is my data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(srvyr)

x  <- structure(list(weight_. = c(0.533483250400349, 0.501519621255761, 
                            0.377142269444863, 0.353321846438303, 0.541351935749236, 0.377142269444863, 
                            0.848202098220559, 0.466419776588491, 0.848202098220559, 0.507159979159623), 
                     region = structure(c(3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("м. Київ", "Північний", "Центральний"), class = "factor"), 
age = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("18-24", "25-34", "35-44", "45+"), class = "factor"), 
gender = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("мужчина", "женщина"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to loop group_by through different columns (in this example it's 'region')

```
x %>%
  as_survey(weights = c(weight_.)) %>%
  group_by(region) %>%
  summarize(n = survey_total(na.rm=T), m =survey_mean(na.rm=T))
```

In result i want to have a list with tibbles like below with grouped summary for each chosen column.

```
A tibble: 3 x 5
  region          n  n_se      m  m_se
  <fct>       <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 м. Київ     3.96  1.01  0.740  0.144
2 Північний   0.860 0.585 0.161  0.115
3 Центральний 0.533 0.533 0.0996 0.100
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. It is very difficult to help you without a testing dataset. You can use the `dput` function to share a portion of your data with us so we can do some tests on it and replicate the error. Also, you might want to share the output that you expect, so we can try to achieve it. (note: use @ to answer a comment, otherwise people are not noticed)

Comment: @DanChaltiel Thank you! I'll update my question to make it more reproducible in a few moments

Answer (score 1):

`group_by_` here would make list of tibbles off of the region/gender vector

```
myfun <-
    function( this_variable ){
        x %>%
          as_survey(weights = c(weight_.)) %>%
          group_by_(this_variable) %>%
          summarize(n = survey_total(na.rm=T), m =survey_mean(na.rm=T))
    }

lapply( c( 'region' , 'gender' ) , myfun )
```